# Function works on each row of data frame, but not using df.apply

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scipy

I have this pandas dataframe containing two samples X and Y for each row:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'X': [np.random.normal(0, 1, 10),
                         np.random.normal(0, 1, 10),
                         np.random.normal(0, 1, 10)],
                   'Y': [np.random.normal(0, 1, 10),
                         np.random.normal(0, 1, 10),
                         np.random.normal(0, 1, 10)]})
```

I want to use a function `ttest_ind()` (a statistical test taking two samples as input) on each row, and take the first element of the response (the function returns two elements):

- If I do it for a given row, e.g. 1st row, it works:

  ```
  from scipy import stats
  stats.ttest_ind(df['X'][0], df['Y'][0], equal_var = False)[0]
  # Returns a float
  ```
- However, if I use apply to do it on each row, I get an error:

  ```
  df.apply(lambda x: stats.ttest_ind(x['X'], x['Y'], equal_var = False)[0])

  # Throws the following error:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 154, in 
  pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 759, in 
  pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
  TypeError: an integer is required
  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
  ...
  KeyError: ('X', 'occurred at index X')
  ```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to specify the axis on which you want to apply your function. Take a look at the relevant [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) for `apply()`. In short, `axis = 1` says "apply the function to each row of my dataframe". The default is `axis = 0`, which tries to apply the function to each column instead.

```
df.apply(lambda x: stats.ttest_ind(x['X'], x['Y'], equal_var = False)[0], axis=1)

0    0.985997
1   -0.197396
2    0.034277
```

Comment: Ah of course! Completely forgot about the axis there. And the error message being not clear at all didn't help to be honest. Thanks.